Knot with 8 crossings
I drew the following knot with 8 crossings:

However, I cannot find it in this classification. Does anybody have suggestions how to determine the label of this knot? I would greatly appreciate your advice.
Here is the before-mentioned list of prime knots with 8 crossings:


According to https://knotfol.io/, this is the 8_20 knot.

@Semiclassical Thank you!
